# How to open Firefox in Full Screen mode?

Tags: firefox, applescript, fullscreen, kiosk-mode

I need to open Firefox on a Mac running Lion in Full Screen mode to act as a kiosk.

I was using the R-Kiosk 0.9.0 Firefox Add-on; but, it conflicts with a print javascript I am also running, so I can't use it.

Anyone know a way to accomplish this? either with an add-on or, perhaps, with AppleScript? Could an AppleScript be triggered to run when Firefox is opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
activate application "Firefox"
delay 2    
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Firefox"
    click menu item "Full Screen" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
end tell
end tell
```

or maybe a keystroke:

```
activate application "Firefox"
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

Comment: Hummm...I get an error message:

System Events got an error: Can't get menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of process "Firefox".

Comment: I tested it with Firefox open. There needs to be a delay added if the application is closed.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from version 71, you can open Firefox with the **--kiosk** parameter to open it in full screen.

Ex:

```
c:\"Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" --kiosk
```