# Open Firefox in Full Screen mode

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, fedora

I'd like my users to open the browser and it goes in to full screen mode immediately.  The configuration is Firefox 42 in Fedora 22.  My application controls the server and the client.  So we could use [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277731/firefox-force-full-screen-mode-from-webpage) (seems not possible for security reasons) or a Firefox extension.  We were using R-Kiosk to do this, but it's not supported in new browsers.  This question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542492/how-to-open-firefox-in-full-screen-mode) except for Fedora.

If there's no way to do this from Firefox, is there a way to do this using the desktop (e.g. desktop icon)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to update R-Kiosk to 0.9.0.1 (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/) and customize it for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful using Firefox 78.0.2 (64-bit) on macos->

[Open div in fullscreen on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418418/open-div-in-fullscreen-on-firefox)

basically you need to change the security configurations of your firefox browser through **about:config** in the URL Search box in Firefox
there change the **full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only** to false

After changing those settings I used this code into my web application via JS and it worked well

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 openFullscreen()
})
let elem = document.documentElement
function openFullscreen() {

  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen()
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen()
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen()
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah and by the way if you want to get rid of the warning to escape fullScreen mode, just change the parameters full-screen-api.warning.delay and full-screen-api.warning.timeout to '0'