# Open div in fullscreen on firefox

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, fullscreen

I am trying to open a div in fullscreen browser mode using the Firefox browser. I can do it successfully in Chrome with the following code but Firefox gives me the following warning in the console

> Request for fullscreen was denied because at least one of the
>   document’s containing elements is not an iframe or does not have an
>   “allowfullscreen” attribute.

My code is as follows

```
  <div id="main">
   ...
  </div>

  full() {
    const elem =  document.getElementById('main');
    const methodToBeInvoked = elem['requestFullscreen'] ||
      elem['webkitRequestFullScreen'] || elem['mozRequestFullscreen']
      || elem['msRequestFullscreen'];
    if (methodToBeInvoked) {
      methodToBeInvoked.call(elem);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser specific security feature in firefox. You can disable the same by following the steps as follows:

- Type `about:config` in the URL Search box in `Firefox`.
- On Config page search for the following key and set the `value` as `false`:

  `full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only`.
- If you also want to remove the browser prompt,when entering fullscreen, set the `value` for following key also as `false`:

  `full-screen-api.approval-required`